# Launch a URL in Google Chrome from Internet Explorer with protocol handler

Tags: windows, google-chrome, internet-explorer, url-scheme, protocol-handler

I want to open a URL in chrome from IE. But the URL that i wanted never opens instead home page of chrome browser opens.

I followed the steps in below link but no luck.

https://www.adamfowlerit.com/2015/05/how-to-launch-a-url-in-google-chrome/

**1.Add the String Value of “URL Protocol” with a blank value to:**

**[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\ChromeHTML] or [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Chrome]**
**(they’re one and the same)**
**“URL Protocol”:””**

**2. Modify the value of**

**[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\ChromeHTML\shell\open\command\Default]**
**“C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe” — %1**

**3. Use a space in the URL after the // you’re using for your link:**

**ChromeHTML:// adamfowlerit.com**

And i tried all possibilities for removing quotes from the parameter but Not Working.

And i looked every related posts in stackoverflow so please don't close this question.

Comment: Is there a space between?

Comment: I tried that but didn't work. Actually when I give the url as static it works but dynamically not working. Is there any way other than %1 to get the parameter?